# datetime в float без использования datediff

Tags: sql, dbeaver

интересует такой вопрос: как можно перевести `datetime` в `float` без использования `datediff`?

Допустим, у меня есть два столбца `testOne` и `testTwo` в одной таблице, включающую в себя информацию следующего вида: `2022-01-02 17:00:00` и `2022-01-01 18:00:00` соответственно.

Необходимо найти разность между этими датами, но не прописывать их, а названия столбцов. Ответ должен быть следующим: `0.958333333333`.

Я понимаю как выполнить данную задачку с конечным переводом в целое число, пример:

> cast(cast(testOne as date) - cast(testTwo as date) as int))

но не очень понимаю как реализовать это с десятичным. Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: Разделить на 86400 или что-то подобное?

Comment: `SELECT (testOne - testTwo) / 86400.0 as diff FROM your_table`